# Cofirmation on command (client.wait_for)

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm having a bit of a hard time. I'm tryin to make the bot ask if they're sure they want to delete 50 messages from a channel saying yes or no, but whenever I try to make 2 client.wait_for's they don't seem to work. This is what I currently got:

````
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.cooldown(1, 15, commands.BucketType.user)
@commands.has_role("Developer")
async def purge(ctx,  amount=50):
  await ctx.reply("This will delete the most recent **50** messages from this channel, are you sure?\n`yes`, `no`")

  def check (message):
    return message.content == 'yes' and message.channel

  msglol = await client.wait_for('yes', check=check)
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount.format(msglol))
  await ctx.reply("Done!", delete_after=5)

  def check (message):
     return message.content == 'no' and message.channel

  msglmao = await client.wait_for('no', check=check)
  await ctx.reply("Ok!".format(msglmao))```
````

Comment: Also no -- it's not that i didn't put "@client.command()" I forgot to paste that in the code ;-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chuaat said, the correct syntax for `client.wait_for` is `wait_for(event, *, check=None, timeout=None)`
however, by your implementation of `wait_for`, it is clear you don't understand how `wait_for` works in the first place.

by using `wait_for` you are making a one time listener of a specific event. In place of event, you can insert all `on_x` (x being a general name) events with a specific check, check will only trigger if all checks are met.

so for example, by doing:

```py
def check(message: discord.Message): # typenhinting for better understand
    return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel
msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check) # msg is a discord.Message object
if msg.content.lower() == 'yes':
   return await ctx.send("oh cool, you said yes")
elif msg.content.lower() == 'no':
   return await ctx.send('oh cool, you said no')
```

the bot makes a one time listener which will look for an 'on_message' event whose `message.author == ctx.author` and whose `message.channel == ctx.channel`

From your implementation, you seem to think you need to open two `wait_for`, one for 'yes' and one for 'no' but that's not the case at all.

Comment: THANK YOU!! I was wondering how you could use multiple wait_for's